# Heap out of memory when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I'm using Eclipse Neon for Ubuntu and I edited `eclipse.ini` by adding `-Xmx8g`, so the Heap can take up to 8gb of ram.

However, my application keeps running out of memory around the same point when I used the default value (`-Xmx1024`). In addition, it's weird that this happens, since  by monitoring the applications it seems that Eclipse takes 1.4Gb, while the application 1.3GB, so less than 8GB for sure.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your application and eclipse run in different JVMs, and the configuration in `eclipse.ini` will only apply to eclipse, not the JVMs it spawns. Check your run configurations for the options of the JVM of your application

Comment: Thanks @Aron , so should I add -Xmxg8 to the run conf too?

Comment: Only to the run configuration, as VM argument

Comment: I think I found out the problem: this application generates an huge amount of output. By deleting all the outputs, the problem was solved. How to avoid it?

Comment: @justHelloWorld then the conclusion is that the output  data stay in memory somewhere (eclipse console?). Writing outputs to regular files shall keep your heap at reasonable level. As a next step, you may always use a profiler and a heap analyzer to see what's taking so much from the heap.